# R - dplyr bootstrap several variables

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying out `bootstraping` with `dplyr` and I am stuck with a simple line of code.

Using the function `bootstrap`, I found [out](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/bootstrapping.html) that it is possible to do

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

mtcars %>% bootstrap(10) %>% 
  do(tidy(sample(.$cyl, 2)))
```

to get a nice straightforward output

```
   replicate     x
         (int) (dbl)
1          1     6
2          1     8
3          2     6
4          2     8
...
```

However, it would be nice to get more variables (columns), but I can't figure it how.

I thought something like

```
mtcars %>% bootstrap(10) %>% 
  do(tidy(sample(., 2)))
```

or

```
mtcars %>% bootstrap(10) %>% 
  do(tidy(sample_n(2)))
```

would work but it doesn't.

Any clue how I can subset several variables ?

Imagine I want to get `mpg`, `cyl` and `disp` to get something like 
(**output**)

```
   replicate   cyl   mpg  disp
        (int) (dbl)
1          1     6   21  ...
2          1     4   22  ...
3          2     6   ... 
4          2     8   ...
...
```

*(I am randomly choosing two cases `sample = 2` and I repeat this routine (`bootstrap`) 10 times)*.

Comment: Is your goal just to get a bunch of random samples w/ replacement _for each column_ in the original data frame? What is the model you are ultimately trying to fit? There are some more examples on bootstrapping with broom in the [bootstrapping vignette](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom/blob/master/vignettes/bootstrapping.Rmd) that may be helpful.

Comment: @Keith, thanks I'll look at it. It is not to fit a model, just data manipulation.  Whoever voted down, can I have an explanation ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
set.seed(123)
sapply(mtcars, function(v) sample(v,2))
```

you can sample 2 values from each column of `mtcars`, where however the columns are sampled *independently of each other* (not sure that this is what you want and/or that it makes sense). Therefore a solution using `broom` might be:

```
mtcars %>%
    bootstrap(10) %>%
    do(tidy(sapply(., function(v) sample(v,2))))
```

If, on the other hand, preserving the relations between the columns is important, you could use something like

```
do.call("rbind",lapply(1:10, function(dum) mtcars[sample.int(nrow(mtcars), 2), ]))
```